# area of rectangle-see figure

Tags: geometry, problem-solving, area

[image]

I am trying to find the area of the green rectangle.
Triangle ABC has area $16$ and triangle CDE has area $4$.
The two triangles have the same shape.

then
$ab=32$,
$cd=4$, and 
$\frac{a}{b} = \frac{c}{d}$ 
I need $b$ and $c$ to calculate the area of the rectangle.
I need a fourth equation. I have tried
$\frac{1}{2}(a+c)(b+d)=20 + bc$ (the area of the big triangle which includes the rectangle)

I have also tried some pythagaros, but I am stuck

Comment: Have you tried using similar triangles?

Comment: yes, the expression a/b=c/d,

Comment: With given areas, by similarity, we can conclude that $a = 2c$ and $b = 2d$.

Comment: But the big triangle is also similar to the two small ones

Comment: $S_{\triangle{CDE}}=4 \implies cd=\color{red}{8}$

Comment: I suspected that a=2c and b=2d and by subsitution of a=2c into a*b=32 I get 2bc=32 and bc=16. (which is correct). But how to show by algebra that a=2c and b=2d ?

Comment: I can set ab/cd=32/8=4, but from that to a=2c and b=2d I would like to show it with algebra

Comment: @BjørnOveSætre There's no "algebraic" way to show this as this arises from the geometric figure.  You have to use the similarity to conclude that.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: areas are proportional to the square of lengths in similar figures , so $\frac{AC}{CE}= \sqrt{\frac{16}{4}}=2\,$. It follows that $\frac{AC}{AE}=\frac{2}{3}\,$, so the area of the big right triangle (which includes both smaller triangles and the rectangle) is $S=S_{ABC} \cdot \left(\frac{AE}{AC}\right)^2 = 16 \cdot \frac{9}{4}=36\,$. Next, subtract the two known areas.

Comment: Thanks, also an elegant solution

Comment: This also contains the proof that $a=2c$ which was desired in comments under the question.

Answer (score 0):

use that $$\tan(\alpha)=\frac{b}{a},\tan(\alpha)=\frac{d}{c},\tan(\alpha)=\frac{d+b}{a+c}$$ and $$\alpha=\angle{CAB}=\angle {ECD}$$ and $$ab=32$$ and $$cd=8$$

Comment: yes thank you just corrected

Comment: Thanks. I also suspected I needed to use some trig

Comment: @BjørnOveSætre You don't need to.  Just basic arithmetic operations will do.

Answer (score 0):

$$\because \triangle ABC \sim \triangle CDE \\ \therefore \frac{a}{c}=\frac{b}{d}=k \\ a=kc, b = kd \\ \because S_{\triangle ABC}=16 \\ \therefore ab=32 \\
\because S_{\triangle CDE}=4 \\ \therefore cd=8 \\ ab=(kc)(kd)=k^2cd \\
32=8k^2 \\ k=2 \quad(-2 \text{ rejected}) \\
S_\color{grey}{\text{gray rectangle}}=bc=(kd)c=k(cd)=2(8)=16$$

Comment: Thanks, I also tried this, but was think that involving quadratics was just more complicated than necessary. But your solution is very elegant

Comment: @BjørnOveSætre I don't think they are really the usual "quadratic equations" you see in ([tag:algebra-precalculus]) as there's neither completing the square, factorization nor $0$ as the right-hand side. I just do normal cancellations and take roots.  That's already the most complicated thing.  The skill $$\frac{a}{c}=\frac{b}{d}=k$$ is *very* common in geometry to expression *common ratio* between different geometric quantities.  If you dig into the (analytic) *defition* of elementary trigonometric functions, you'll be shocked by the deepness and the beauty behind. It's anything but trivial.

Answer (score 0):

One more attempt:

1)$ab=32;$ 2) $cd=8; $

3) $(a+c)(d+b)=2 (16+4+ bc).$

$ad +ab +cd +cb =  40 +2bc;$

$ad + 32 +8  +cb = 40 +2bc;$

$ad=bc;$

1)×2):

$abcd=32×8 = 256;$

Since $ad = bc:$

$(bc)^2 = 256;$

$bc=16.$

Answer (score 0):

Let the needed area be equal to $x$.

Thus, $$\frac{16+4+x}{16}=\left(\frac{AC}{AE}\right)^2=\left(1+\frac{CE}{AE}\right)^2=\left(1+\frac{1}{2}\right)^2=\frac{9}{4},$$
which gives $x=16.$